# True - False dilemma

Tags: python, variables, python-2.7, boolean

I can't understand what is happening here?

```
True = False
False = True
print True, False
```

#### output

```
False False
```

Isn't the output be printed as `False True`?

Comment: Why on earth would anybody do this?

Comment: You seem to be using Python 2

Comment: Doesn't work on Python 3

Comment: Try `True, False = False, True`.

Comment: You've made a classic mistake that would apply to **any** swapping of two names. `a, b = 10, 42; a = b; b = a; print a, b` prints `42 42`. This is not unique to booleans.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are setting `True = False`, **and then** `False = True`.

```
True = False
False = True # But "True" here is now False.
print True, False # True = False, because of the first line. As does False, because you set it equal to "True" which you have already made == False.
```

I don't know why you would ever want to do this, other than to mess with someone's code, as it's a readability nightmare - as you can see just from the difficulty in using the words to explain it.

If you really want to swap the vaules around, then do:

```
True, False = False, True
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be using Python 2.

This wouldn't work in Python 3 as `True` and `False` were changed to keywords in order to make assignment to those impossible.

Refer to Core Language Changes:

> Make `True` and `False` keywords. [[6]](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2004-July/046294.html)
>
> ```
> Reason: make assignment to them impossible.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Once you do `True = False`, `True` is no longer a boolean but rather a variable that has been assigned the boolean `False`. Therefore, the line `False = True` is actually assigning `True`'s value (`False`) to the *variable* `False`.